# Measure movement distance - not sure what sensor?

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to measure the length of a step / stride -not sure what sensor to use.

I am trying to get several people to march a pattern for a band.  I am thinking a Arduino to beep when step is too short or too small.  Thinking the Arduino will be tied to their shoe laces.  IR or Ultrasonic do not seem to be the correct sensor to use.

Ideas?

Comment: Maybe just go lowtech and simply use rope? Tie person ankles together to train muscle memory when walking. Doing precise measurements quickly and in uncontrolled enviroment is a nightmare to sensors.

Comment: Or, to pick up Filip Franiks idea, use a small rope on a coil, that will roll itself up automatically. A step would roll some rope of the coil and you can measure the amount by measuring the rotation of the coil (for example with a rotary encoder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sensor to use is an accelerometer. The principle is easy: measure the acceleration, perform a double integration and you have the distance (after the first integration you have the velocity).

The problem is that, because of the double integration, small errors in the acceleration signal lead to big errors in the calculated distance. For example: an error e in the acceleration leads to an error e.t<sup>2</sup> in the distance (where t stands for time). For this reason al sorts of filters are used often in combination with gyroscopes and/or gravity sensors. The signals from the gyroscopes and/or gravity sensors are used for the low frequency signals (long term) and te signals from the accelerometer(s) for the high frequency signals (short variations). That's why you find these sensors often combined in one package (for example the BNO055 form Robot Electronics https://robot-electronics.co.uk/bno055.html).

It is a complicated and highly mathematical area of science. In fact you want to do the same thing as fitness trackers do (and I think you are striving to a higher accuracy than they) - and there are not many that do really well.

P.S. Robot Electronics also sell a tilt compensated compass board with this BNO055 chip: the CMPS12 (https://robot-electronics.co.uk/cmps12-tilt-compensated-magnetic-compass.html). With this board you can read out absolute and relative positions straight away without any calculations.